# Javascript - evaluating parameter again

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a function "when", that will work as a normal command, or just a function, and will be able to re-evaluate its parameters.
for example:

```
when(k==0) {
  do something;
}
```

or

```
when(k==0, function() {
  do something;
});
```

The thing is, that k is now for example equal to 1, and this function needs to always re-evaluate k==0 to determinate if it changed to 0.

*I do not want to send k==0 as a string 'k==0'.

Is that possible? If so, how?

*This is an academic question, please don't explain why it is so very wrong to create this function.

Comment: I think this function already exists and is called "if". Like `if(k==0){ do sth. }`.

Comment: You seem to be looking for some kind of mechanism for observing when a variable's value changes. No such thing is available in JS.

Comment: @migg "if" evaluates the condition once, and drops it. I think of something that runs forever and always evaluates.

Comment: @torazaburo This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for the info.

Comment: Why not make the condition a callback too? So `when (function() { return k == 0; }, function() { do something });`

Comment: @Zastai This is the best solution, and a working one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would work would be to use a lambda for both the condition and the action. Using arrow function expressions (thanks @Kyll), it's even reasonably compact.

```
when (() => k == 0, () => { do something; });
```

Comment: Would look way better with an arrow function! `when(() => condition, action)`

Comment: My JS-fu is rusty at best. Just added an answer because it looked like my comment was enough for the OP. Should've looked it up first, but none of the other comments/answers used anything other than function expressions. Will edit the answer.

Answer (score 3):

something like this?

```
function when(condition, callback){ if (condition) callback() }
```

and call it like

```
var a = 0;
when(a == 0, function(){ console.log( "yeyyyy") } );
```

after reading the comments above

> some kind of mechanism for observing when a variable's value changes

change `when` method to

```
function when(lhs, operator, rhs, callback)
{ 
   var result = false;
   switch( operator )
   {
      case "==": result = (lhs==rhs); break;
      case "===": result = (lhs===rhs); break;
      case "<": result = (lhs<rhs); break;
      case ">": result = (lhs>rhs); break;
      case "<=": result = (lhs<=rhs); break;
      case ">=": result = (lhs>=rhs); break;
      default: result = true;
   }
   if (result) { callback() }
   else { setTimeout( function(){ when(lhs, operator, rhs, callback) }, 1000 ); } 
}
```

Comment: Not exactly.. when you send a==0 to the function, in this case it sends "true". I want to send the actual condition if possible, and then evaluate it inside the function. "when" is a function that has a timeout of 1 millisecond, and every 1 millisecond checks if a==0. if it is true, now it will run the callback function, and stop the timeout.

Comment: @Amit after reading your comments above, i think you will need to construct an expression in the method itself. For this you will need to pass the all three to when (lhs, rhs and operator). Check the updated code now.